# How can a flavour changing neutral current be drawn for the higgs decay to two down-type quarks?

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams, higgs

I am trying to draw a Feynman diagram for the decay $ h \rightarrow d+\bar{s} $, but I'm struggling to create one which makes sense. So far I have this diagram:

[image].

Please could someone explain what is wrong with it and why (if it is wrong), and also more generally how FCNC Feynman diagrams are structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were already on the right track.
But in your Feynman diagram you have drawn the $u$ an $\bar{s}$
as incoming particles, instead of outgoing.
So your diagram actually describes the process
$$h+d+\bar{s} \to \text{nothing}$$

For describing the process
$$h \to d+\bar{s}$$
the Feynman diagram would look like this.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, my confusion was that I thought the W boson coupled to a quark and an anti quark, not two antiquarks/two quarks, is this not the case?

Comment: @John The W boson can do all of these.

Comment: Okay thanks for the answer - that's why I had the weird umbrella shape.